# Unusual Count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame df that looks like -

```
attribute_ids                     attributes_names
['adr4r','5ty6gh']                ['abc','xyz'] 
['fg67y','ty67g','ght43','adr4r'] ['pqr','abc','xyz','abc']
```

I want to count the number of times each unique atrribute_id exists and display it in the descending order. But in the result i want to display its corresponding attribute_names also. Please be aware that attribute names aren't unique, attribute_ids are. For example: `adr4r` and `ty67g` bith have the same name "abc". Output should look like -

```
attribute_ids       atribute_names     count
adr4r               abc                2
ty67g               abc                1
5ty6gh              xyz                1
ght43               xyz                1
fg67y               pqr                1
```

Currently I am able to count on the basis of attribute_ids alone (not able to display corresponding attribute_names):

```
count=df.attribute_ids.apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`pir1`

- concatenate columns together with [**`np.concatenate`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)
- use [**`np.unique`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to identify unique values, and ...

  - count occurrences of those values with parameter `return_counts=True`
  - index of where the first occurrences happened so I can slice `names` using parameter `return_index=True`

---

```
ids = np.concatenate(df.attribute_ids)
names = np.concatenate(df.attribute_names)

u, idx, cts = np.unique(ids, return_index=True, return_counts=True)

pd.DataFrame(dict(
    attribute_ids=u,
    attribute_names=names[idx],
    count=cts
))

  attribute_ids attribute_names  count
0        5ty6gh             xyz      1
1         adr4r             abc      2
2         fg67y             pqr      1
3         ght43             xyz      1
4         ty67g             abc      1
```

---

**Option 2**
`pir2`

- Like in option 1, we flatten the columns
- Then use grouping on the `attribute_ids` column followed by `agg`

---

```
from cytools import concat

d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    attribute_ids=list(concat(df.attribute_ids.values.tolist())),
    attribute_names=list(concat(df.attribute_names.values.tolist()))
))

d1.groupby('attribute_ids').attribute_names.agg(['first', 'count']) \
    .reset_index().rename(columns=dict(first='attribute_names'))

  attribute_ids attribute_names  count
0        5ty6gh             xyz      1
1         adr4r             abc      2
2         fg67y             pqr      1
3         ght43             xyz      1
4         ty67g             abc      1
```

---

**Option 3**
`pir3`
Use `pd.factorize` on tuples.  Use `concat` to flatten arrays.

```
from cytoolz import concat

i = concat(df.attribute_ids.values.tolist())
n = concat(df.attribute_names.values.tolist())
f, u = pd.Series(list(zip(i, n))).factorize()
return pd.DataFrame(
    u.tolist(),
    columns=['attribute_ids', 'attribute_names']
).assign(count=np.bincount(f))

  attribute_ids attribute_names  count
0         adr4r             abc      2
1        5ty6gh             xyz      1
2         fg67y             pqr      1
3         ty67g             abc      1
4         ght43             xyz      1
```

---

**Timing**

```
results.div(results.min(1), 0).round(2).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(Best=d.idxmin(1)))

        pir1  pir2  pir3  galt  Best
N                                   
1       1.00  4.37  1.75  4.07  pir1
3       1.00  3.84  1.54  4.58  pir1
10      1.48  2.46  1.00  2.38  pir3
30      2.42  3.09  1.00  2.86  pir3
100     5.56  2.42  1.00  2.58  pir3
300    14.86  2.52  1.00  2.42  pir3
1000   24.63  1.37  1.00  1.43  pir3
3000   38.14  1.47  1.00  1.35  pir3
10000  41.85  1.36  1.00  1.14  pir3
```

---

```
fig, (a1, a2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(6, 6))
results.plot(loglog=True, lw=3, ax=a1)
results.div(results.min(1), 0).round(2).plot.barh(logx=True, ax=a2)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

**Code**

```
def galt(df):
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    return pd.DataFrame({
        c: [v for L in df[c] for v in L] for c in cols
    }).groupby(cols).size().reset_index(name='count')

def pir1(df):
    ids = np.concatenate(df.attribute_ids)
    names = np.concatenate(df.attribute_names)

    u, idx, cts = np.unique(ids, return_index=True, return_counts=True)

    return pd.DataFrame(dict(
        attribute_ids=u,
        attribute_names=names[idx],
        count=cts
    ))

def pir2(df):
    d1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        attribute_ids=list(concat(df.attribute_ids.values.tolist())),
        attribute_names=list(concat(df.attribute_names.values.tolist()))
    ))

    return d1.groupby('attribute_ids').attribute_names.agg(['first', 'count']) \
        .reset_index().rename(columns=dict(first='attribute_names'))

def pir3(df):
    i = concat(df.attribute_ids.values.tolist())
    n = concat(df.attribute_names.values.tolist())
    f, u = pd.Series(list(zip(i, n))).factorize()
    return pd.DataFrame(
        u.tolist(),
        columns=['attribute_ids', 'attribute_names']
    ).assign(count=np.bincount(f))


results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000], name='N'),
    columns='pir1 pir2 pir3 galt'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in results.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setp, number=10))
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    attribute_ids=[['adr4r', '5ty6gh'], ['fg67y', 'ty67g', 'ght43', 'adr4r']],
    attribute_names=[['abc', 'xyz'], ['pqr', 'abc', 'xyz', 'abc']]
))
```

Comment: `concat` function is from ..?

Comment: Thanks for catching that

Comment: Thanks for the timings, appreciate it.

Comment: Thats an amazing solution @piRSquared. What if I want to display the result in descending order. I am using option 1 in your solution.

Comment: @Learning I've updated my post.  You can use `.sort_values('count', ascending=False)` to sort if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, by flattening the dataframe

```
In [1292]: cols = df.columns.tolist()

In [1293]: (pd.DataFrame({c: [v for L in df[c] for v in L] for c in cols})
              .groupby(cols).size())
Out[1293]:
attribute_ids  attributes_names
5ty6gh         xyz                 1
adr4r          abc                 2
fg67y          pqr                 1
ght43          xyz                 1
ty67g          abc                 1
dtype: int64
```

Details

```
In [1294]: df
Out[1294]:
                  attribute_ids      attributes_names
0               [adr4r, 5ty6gh]            [abc, xyz]
1  [fg67y, ty67g, ght43, adr4r]  [pqr, abc, xyz, abc]

In [1295]: cols = df.columns
Out[1295]: ['attribute_ids', 'attributes_names']

In [1296]: {c: [v for L in df[c] for v in L] for c in cols}
Out[1296]:
{'attribute_ids': ['adr4r', '5ty6gh', 'fg67y', 'ty67g', 'ght43', 'adr4r'],
 'attributes_names': ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr', 'abc', 'xyz', 'abc']}

In [1297]: pd.DataFrame({c: [v for L in df[c] for v in L] for c in cols})
Out[1297]:
  attribute_ids attributes_names
0         adr4r              abc
1        5ty6gh              xyz
2         fg67y              pqr
3         ty67g              abc
4         ght43              xyz
5         adr4r              abc
```

Alternatively, if you want series of tuples

```
In [1311]: pd.Series(list(
                zip(*[[v for L in df[c] for v in L] for c in cols]))).value_counts()
Out[1311]:
(adr4r, abc)     2
(fg67y, pqr)     1
(ght43, xyz)     1
(ty67g, abc)     1
(5ty6gh, xyz)    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Timings if you're interested.